# bitbake recipe for installing deb package

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I want to install my own custom deb package in yocto image. For this I am using following *mydebpkg.bb* recipe using *ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND*

```
SUMMARY = "Recipe for installing deb package"
DESCRIPTION = "It installs own deb package"
HOMEPAGE = "" 
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

inherit bin_package

my_install_pkg_deb() {

${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/dpkg \

--root=${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/ --admindir=${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/var/lib/dpkg/  \

-i /home/pi1/install/own_1.3-07u_armhf.deb

}

ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND +=  "my_install_pkg_deb; "
```

But while building image the process fails with following error *cannot install package mydebpkg* and *Function failed: do_rootfs*. Where I am making mistake and what will be the correct recipe for installing any deb package.

Comment: If i remember, Debian packages are not compatible with yocto .deb packages. So you have to generate your own package with Yocto, then add it like every other packages with `IMAGE_INSTALL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing precompiled .deb is an awful decision, you should avoid doing so anytime you are able to compile the package from source code. If this isn't the case, I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
SUMMARY = "Recipe for installing deb package"
DESCRIPTION = "It installs own deb package"
HOMEPAGE = ""
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

DEPENDS += " dpkg-native "

SRC_URI += " \
    file://own_1.3-07u_armhf.deb.zip \
"

do_install_append() {
    touch ${STAGING_DIR_NATIVE}/var/lib/dpkg/status
    ${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/dpkg --instdir=${D}/ \
    --admindir=${STAGING_DIR_NATIVE}/var/lib/dpkg/ \
     -i ${WORKDIR}/own_1.3-07u_armhf.deb
}
```

So: use SRC_URI variable to let bitbake copy your .deb file to the working dir. I suggest you zip the file as bitbake tries to unpack all the archives you supply him, and .deb is just another archive. So pack it to zip and let bitbake bring your .deb file to the working directory. Place your .deb.zip file by */path/to/your/recipe*/files folder. Remember: **never** use absolute paths in yocto!
Then in do_install function invoke dpkg to install your .deb file into deploy dir of your package. This code is not complete as in case of a successful installation (don't forget about conflict resolution), you will get a list of files and directories that installed but not shipped in any package. You will need to add to your recipe `FILES_${PN}` variable:

```
FILES_${PN} += " \
    /usr/bin/some_file \
    /etc/some_config_file \
    /and_so_on \
"
```

The complete list what you need to add you can get from the error message.
And remember: this method will only work if your target architecture is the same as your host architecture. Regarding that you used `STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE` variable this is the case, regarding that your package contains `arm`, this isn't.

Comment: There is an option to turn off the unpacking. Just append the `SRC_URI` with `;unpack=0`. Much simpler than zipping the dependency so bitbake can undo it.

Comment: Please can you be more specific on why it is `an awful decision` to use prebuilt packages?

Comment: for building to arm you can use the dpkg option '--force architecture'

Comment: Is anybody able to convert this script to the current syntax? bitbake is complaining that it uses some old override syntax. I'm, stuck...

Comment: Basically, this thing is needed when there is a proprietary package (for example, Pylon SDK).